# Volley not making requests

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley

My app is supposed to grab data from a database and display it in a recyclerview, I am however getting an error **2020-08-16 18:12:01.712 29166-29166/com.example.mn E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout** below is code for my main activity

```
package com.example.mn;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //this is the JSON Data URL
    
    private static final String URL_PRODUCTS = "https://myUrl/russell/api.php";

    //a list to store all the products
    List<Product> productList;

    //the recyclerview
    RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //getting the recyclerview from xml
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        //initializing the productlist
        productList = new ArrayList<>();

        //this method will fetch and parse json
        //to display it in recyclerview
        loadProducts();
    }

    private void loadProducts() {

        /*
         * Creating a String Request
         * The request type is GET defined by first parameter
         * The URL is defined in the second parameter
         * Then we have a Response Listener and a Error Listener
         * In response listener we will get the JSON response as a String
         * */
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL_PRODUCTS,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            //converting the string to json array object
                            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);

                            //traversing through all the object
                            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {

                                //getting product object from json array
                                JSONObject product = array.getJSONObject(i);

                                //adding the product to product list
                                productList.add(new Product(
                                        product.getInt("id"),
                                        product.getString("title"),
                                        product.getString("shortdesc")
                                ));
                            }

                            //creating adapter object and setting it to recyclerview
                            ProductsAdapter adapter = new ProductsAdapter(MainActivity.this, productList);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    }
                });

        //adding our stringrequest to queue
        Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

I have put two break points as in the screenshot and it never reaches the second break point

[image]

What could be the problem

Comment: Giving ListItems to Adapter in the constructor is not a good idea. I suggest you create an adapter in onCreate then attach it to RecyclerView. Then Below set items to the adapter. After setting items to your adapter call notifyDataSetChanged() in your adapter. DONE

Answer (score 0):

As the comment pointed out there are better ways to do this but if you are starting out it might be hard to do all of those at once.

I can however tell you a quick fix, which should be just setting the RecyclerView to an empty list at the start so it has a adapter (with 0 items)

```
ProductsAdapter adapter = new ProductsAdapter(this, new ArrayList<Product>());
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This would be directly after setting the LayoutManager

Answer (score 0):

After recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter) also specify
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();